# Fallacy of arguments

Tags: fallacies

Does the following argument involve a fallacy?

My garden will be healthy if I water the plants assiduously. Thus my garden will certainly be healthy, as I will indeed water the plants assiduously.

(a) undistributed middle

(b) denying the antecedent

(c) affirming the consequent

(d) no fallacy: deductively valid

Comment: Is it deductively valid?

Comment: You neither accept nor comment any of the answers/comments to your previous posts; why do you go on submitting new questions ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am uncertain of what I have to do? Please elaborate on how to do so ?

Comment: This certainly looks like asking us to do your homework. In that case: What are your thoughts? Not just "is the answer (d)" but "I think the answer is (d) because...".

Answer (score 2):

The argument is deductively valid (though it rests on an assumption about the future).

You can reformulate it as a basic modus ponens as follows:

1. If I water the plants assiduously, my garden will be healthy
2. I will water the plants assiduously

Therefore,
3. My garden will be healthy